# How to retrieve specific elements of a multi-dimensional array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am building a homelab dashboard using php and html. Currently I am attempting to take information from an array and display it within a div. The information provided in the array is the url for an iframe as well as height and width adjustements. My question is how would I retrieve specific elements of this array so I can display it correctly.

```
$dl = [
    'dashlet1' => [
        'url' => 'some random url',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        'width' => 'width=450'
    ],
    'dashlet2' => [
        'url' => 'another random url',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        "width" => 'width=450'
    ],
    'dashlet3' => [
        'url' => 'another random url',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        'width' => 'width=450'
    ],
    'dashlet4' => [
        'url' => 'another random url',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        'width' => 'width=350'
    ],
    'dashlet5' => [
        'url' => 'another random url',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        'width' => 'width=450'
    ],
    'dashlet6' => [
        'url' => 'another random url',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        'width' => 'width=450'
    ],
    'dashlet7' => [
        'url' => 'another random url',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        'width' => 'width=350'
    ],
    'dashlet8' =>[
        'url' => 'another random url',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        'width' => 'width=450'
    ]

];
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Start reading a manual and [mcve]

Comment: To get a specific element, for example, `$dl['dashlet6']['url']`. [See the docs for array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you want to access the url. You can do this by doing

```
echo $dl['dashlet1']['url'];
echo $dl['dashlet2']['url'];
```

etc.

You can also use a loop.

```
    foreach( $dl as $key => $value ) {

        echo($key . " " . $value['url']);
    }
```